# Datepicker not working for a field in node edit form pulled with drupal_get_form

Tags: forms, datetime, javascript

I have a custom table that pulls all the node of a 'seminar' content type and displays it in this way.

```
 Nid | Speaker_name | Speaker_language | Date | Edit
 --------------------------------------------
 124 | Sanjok       |     Eng         |  12-09-2017     | editlink
 *****************************************************************
 125 | Sam          |     Spanish     |   12-10-2017    | editlink
 *****************************************************************
```

Each `editlink` is linked to a bootstrap popup modal which renders respective node edit form.
The node form is rendered this way.

```
$node = node_load($singlerow['nid]);
$popup_form = drupal_get_form('seminar_node_form',$node);
print drupal_render($popup_form);
```

I wanted a popup node edit functionality where the admin/editor does not need to go to /admin/content to edit/update the node. The form is rendered perfectly in a popup modal fashion except for the date field which does not display the default drupal datepicker. I have added the required datepicker.js files located on my `base_url().'misc/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js'` on my template file and on the table file but the datepicker does not work for some reason. 
PS the consolelog does not throw any error as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of experimenting I finally found a workaround. On my template file I used a `preprocess_page` function to add my required js

```
   drupal_add_js(base_path().'misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js', array( 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5));
   drupal_add_js(base_path().'misc/ui/ate_popup/jquery.timeentry.pack.js', array( 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5));
   drupal_add_js(base_path().'misc/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js', array( 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5));
```

And on my custom Js script file I did this. Since all my date input field had a class `date-clear`

```
$('body').on('focus','.date-clear',function(){
      $(this).datepicker({dateFormat: 'd M yy'});
});
```

Obviously this answer can be improved but for now, this does to me.